# В iOS Safari не работает box-shadow у первого input

Tags: css, css3

Обыкновенная форма, внутри инпуты, стили safari обнулены в начале css файла, дальше уже стили для инпутов свои идут.

```
.block1-form form input[type="text"], 
.block1-form form input[type=tel], 
.remodal form input[type="text"], 
.remodal form input[type=tel] {
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left: 20px;
  color: #7e7e7e;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px rgba(81,81,81,0.75);
  background: #ffffff;
}
```

Порядок поле в форме:
type text
type tel
type submit

И вот почему-то в первом инпуте (text) упорно не работает внутренняя тень, а во втором (tel) нормально всё. Не пойму, в чём может быть дело?

Answer (score 1):

Моя невнимательность, оказывается, я обнулил в начале стилевого файла -webkit-appearance не для инпутов в целом, а только для tel и submit. Сам не понимаю, что мною в тот момент двигало. Но именно этот косяк и перебивал тень.